# Rspec: Skipping an exclusion filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have some slow RSpec tests that I've tagged with `:slow`. I've set RSpec up to skip them default by adding the line `config.filter_run_excluding slow: true` to my RSpec configuration. And I can run the slow tests by running `rspec --tag slow`.

But how can I run **all** the tests using one command, including slow and non-slow tests? I can't figure it out from the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a similar question here : [Command line to run all examples in RSpec, including ones that are filtered out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12861627/command-line-to-run-all-examples-in-rspec-including-ones-that-are-filtered-out)

In few words, this feature doesn't exist on rspec but you can use env variable :

```
RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.filter_run_excluding slow: true unless ENV['ALL']
end
```

Call `ALL=1 rspec` will run all the specs including the slow tag.