# How do I run all rspec tests -- even those excluded by default?

Tags: ruby, rspec, tags

Turns out this question is a duplicate of [Command line to run all examples in RSpec, including ones that are filtered out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12861627/command-line-to-run-all-examples-in-rspec-including-ones-that-are-filtered-out/12863729#12863729)

(Good catch, @anothermh.  My google skills failed today.)

---

How do I run all rspec tests -- even those excluded by default?

Several of my tests are tagged with `:slow`, and I have these tests excluded by default:

```
config.filter_run_excluding slow: true
```

Running `rspec` executes all the tests except the "slow" ones (as desired).

Running `rspec --tag slow` executes the "slow" tests only.

What command do I use to run *all* the tests, including the slow ones (without having to use two separate commands)?

Comment: You can just comment out that line. Not sure there's a more automatic way of doing that, but keep in mind that is just Ruby code, so you can always gate it with something like `unless ENV['DO_THE_SLOW_STUFF_TOO']`.

Comment: Looks like you can't as of 2012: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12863729/3784008